# A Realtime Dashboard For Logs

Tags: python, logging, nginx, infrastructure

We have a number of Python services, many of which use Nginx as a reverse proxy. Right now, we examine requests in real time by tailing the logs found in /var/log/nginx/access.log. I want to make these logs publicly readable in aggregate on a webserver so people don't have to SSH into individual machines.

Our current infrastructure has fluentd (a tool similar to logstash I'm told) sending logs up to a centralized stats server, which has Elasticsearch and kibana installed, with the idea being that kibana would serve as the frontend for viewing our logs.

I know nothing about these services. If I wanted to view our logs in realtime, would this stack even be feasible? Can Elasticsearch provide realtime data with a mere second's delay? Does kibana have out-of-the-box functionality for automatically updating the page as new log data comes in (i.e., does it have a socket connection with elasticsearch? Or am I falling into the wrong toolset?

Comment: You could have answered your questions by simply reading the [documentation of the individual components](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/), I'm not sure what is the point of posting your question here.

Comment: I disagree. I read it all but have left with the sense that most people use it for analytics on old log data. The word 'real time' is thrown around but I didn't get any good examples of what I'm looking for. Hence coming here, hoping for people with experience in my exact situation.

Answer (score 1):

Kibana is just an interface on top of elastic search. It talks *directly to elasticsearch*, so the data on it is as *realtime as the data you are feeding into elasticsearch*.  In other words, its only as good as your collectors (fluentd in your case).

It works by having you define time series which it uses to query data from elastic search, and then you can have it always search for keywords and then visualize that data.

If by "realtime" you mean that you want the graphs to move/animate - this is also possible (its called "streaming dashboards"); but that's not the real power of kibana - the real power is a very rich query engine, drill down into time series, do calculations (top x over period y).

If all you want is a nice visual/moving thing to place on the wall tv - this is possible with kibana, but keep in mind you'll have to store everything in elasticsearch so unless you plan on doing some other analysis, you'll have to adjust your configuration. For example, have a really short TTL for the messages so once they are visualized, they are no longer available; or filter fluentd to only send across those events that you want to plot. Otherwise you'll have a disk space problem.

If that is all that you want, it would be a easier to grab some javascript charting library and use that in your portal.

Answer (score 1):

I have the "access.log (or other logs) - logstash (or other ES indexer) - Kibana" pipeline setup for a number of services and logs and it works well. In our case it has more than a second of delay but that's because of buffering in logs or the ES indexer, not because of Kibana/ES itself.

You can setup Kibana to show only the last X minutes of data and refresh every Y seconds, which gives a decent real-time feel - and looks good on TVs ;)

Keep in mind that Kibana can sometimes issue pretty bad queries which can crash your ES cluster (although this seems to have vastly improved in more recent ES and Kibana versions), so do not rely on this as a permanent data store for your logs, and do not share the ES cluster you use for Kibana with apps that have stronger HA requirements.

As Burhan Khalid pointed out, this setup also gives us the ability to drill down and study specific patterns in details, which is super useful ("What's this spike on this graph?" - zoom in, add a couple filters, look at a few example log lines, filter again - mystery solved). I think saving us from having to dig somewhere else to get more details when we see something weird is actually the best part of this solution.